# C drive partitoning/ formating simple volume

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, hard-drive, format

My C Hard drive is a simple volume and will not split.

Wondering if i can format or change my C drive to a primary partition (so it will split) or if i can install ubuntu straight onto my C Drive and keep Windows 7.

Comment: I do but when i click on it, the window "Querying Shrink Space" doesn't disapear and i end up having to close the program. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: I normally takes a while.  How big is your Hard Drive?

Comment: My HD is 281 GB Ill try again and I will leave it up for 20 mins. Hopefully it wont take that long though

Comment: To people voting to close this question: This is about getting the disk ready to install Ubuntu, so it's definitely on-topic for our site.

Comment: How much free space do you actually have?  that could speed up a "you can't" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to computer management.  Right right click on the partition, and choose shrink.  That will let you make room on your drive.

[image]

You will then get a box asking you how much space you want to shrink.  Choose the amount that you like, and click on Shrink.

[image]